# What's wrong with this Julia function?

Tags: julia

I am trying to create sparse matrix in Julia but I presently encounter this problem:

`ERROR: MethodError: no method matching createA(::DataFrame)`

What am I doing wrong? How do I fix it?
This is the code:

```
import SparseMatrixDicts
import DataFrames  
import CSV
function createA()

t1 = argmin(argmax(keg[Array(keg[:dad]  .> 0) .& Array(argmax(keg[:mum] .> 0))]))
t2 = argmax(keg[:ID])
A = SparseMatrixDicts(t2, t2)
diagm(A) = 2-0.5^(keg[:GEN] -1)

  for t in t1:t2
  A[t,t]= sum(c(A[t,t], 0.5^(keg[t,"GEN"])*A[keg[t,"dad"],keg[t,"mum"]]))

    vec = 1:(t-1)


    A[t, vec]= 0.5 * sum(c(A[vec,keg[t,"dad"]],A[vec,keg[t,"mum"]]))
    A[vec,t]= A[t,vec]


  return (A)
  end
end 

keg = DataFrame(ID = [1,2,3,4,6,5,7],
                dad = [0,0,1,1,1,3,5],
                mum = [0,0,0,2,4,4,6],
                GEN = [1,1,2,2,3,3,4]
                )

wish = createA(keg)
```

Answer (score 4):

You’ve defined a function, `createA`, taking no arguments and then call it with one argument, which doesn’t work, of course. Try declaring the function as `function createA(keg)` instead.

Comment: I have removed the get but still experiencing same error

Comment: The get isn’t the issue, it’s just confusing. The issue js that createA takes no arguments.

Comment: ```ERROR: MethodError: no method matching get(::DataFrame)``` This was the error after declaring it as ```function create(keg)```

Comment: Your question was answered. But there are other problems with your function, so when you solve one problem you will get errors from others. In this case the syntax `keg[t,"GEN"]` doesn't exist.

Comment: Ok, this is my first Julia script and still learning, what should be there instead?

Comment: It's an ambitious first script.  Perhaps, a tutorial or two ? "A Deep Introduction to Julia for Data Science and Scientific Computing"  by Chris Rackauckas @user:1544203  and http://ucidatascienceinitiative.github.io/IntroToJulia..  Lots more. plus an active https://www.reddit.com/r/Julia/